# Monotouch - playing video on network share

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, video-streaming

We are building an application that will only be used within our infrastructure. We have videos on a windows file share which we want to play within the app. The videos are working when they are embeded in the app but as some of them are so big we want to move them out.

I am trying to reference the videos using an smb:// url but that doesn't seem to work.

I am also trying to reference them using a file:// url to no avail. I can see the folder from the dev mac.

Should this work or do I need to do more work to make it happen? Such as streaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS is not able to access any kind of shared directory (smb:// or file://), you will have to add code to your app to connect and transfer the files yourself if you want to use a shared directory like that.

But iOS can access web servers, so if you can set up a simple http server (Apache or IIS), and serve the files using a http protocol, it should work just fine.